# When does an element of $\mathrm{Sl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ preserve a scalar product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was asking myself the following question : when does an element of $\mathrm{Sl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ preserve a certain scalar product ? A simple necessary condition is that it's complex eigenvalues are of modulus 1. I think it must be diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ too.

Can one find a sufficient condition ?

Comment: Preserving scalar product is the same as being orthogonal. What you are looking for are elements of $SO_n(\mathbb{R})$, the special orthogonal group.

Comment: Not really. I'm looking for conjugates of the orthogonal group since the scalar product is not necesserally the canonical euclidean product in the canonical basis.

Comment: For example any conjugate of a rotation preserve a scalar product, but does not belong to $O_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: The question you’re asking is not quite clear. Are you asking for which matrices there exists a certain scalar product preserved by them ?

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm not sure how to be clearer :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Under what conditions is a linear automorphism an isometry of some inner product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229804/under-what-conditions-is-a-linear-automorphism-an-isometry-of-some-inner-product)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The necessary condition you stated is also sufficient. Indeed, suppose
$A\in SL_n({\mathbb R})$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$ and all that its
eigenvalues have modulus $1$.

We need the following :

**Kernel invariance property** Let $L/K$ be any extension of fields. 
Let $B$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with coefficients in $K$. Then there is a basis
in $K^n$ of ${\sf Ker}_{K^n}(B)$, that can also serve as 
a basis of ${\sf Ker}_{L^n}(B)$ (in particular the two kernels have the same
dimension).

This invariance property follows form Gauss’ method to
[reduce to row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).
The computations will be identical in $K^n$ and in $L^n$. And 
as this method only involves additions, substractions and multiplications,
if the coefficients of $B$ are in $K$, all the computations will stay in $K$.

Denote the real eigenvalues of $A$ by $\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \ldots ,\lambda_r$
and $\alpha_1\pm i\beta_1, \alpha_2\pm i\beta_2, \ldots, \alpha_s\pm i\beta_s$.
Thus each $\lambda_j$ is $\pm 1$ and each $\alpha_j^2+\beta_j^2$ is $1$.

Since $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$, there is a basis
$(b_1,b_2,\ldots ,b_n)$ of ${\mathbb C}^n$ with
$Ab_{2j-1}=(\alpha_j-i\beta_j)b_{2j-1}$ and
$Ab_{2j}=(\alpha_j+i\beta_j)b_{2j-1}$ for $1\leq j\leq s$,
and $Ab_k=\lambda_kb_k$ for $2s < k \leq n$. For every $j$ we can write $b_{2j}=x_j+iy_j$ where $x_j$ and $y_j$ have real
coordinates.  As $A$ has real coefficients, we see that for every $j$  we have

$$
Ax_j=\alpha_j x_j-\beta_j y_j, Ay_j=\beta_j x_j+\alpha_j y_j \tag{1}
$$

By the kernel invariance property (consider $B=A-\lambda I$ for $\lambda$ an 
eigenvalue), we can assume without loss that the $b_k (2s < k\leq n)$ have real coefficients.

Let $\alpha+\beta i$ be a complex eigenvalue of $A$. We shall denote by $K_{\mathbb R}$ ($K_{\mathbb C}$) the kernel of $(A-\alpha I)^2+\beta^2$ in 
${\mathbb R}^n$ (${\mathbb C}^n$). By construction, $K_{\mathbb R}$ and 
$K_{\mathbb C}$ are invariant by $A$. Let $W$ be a subspace of
$K_{\mathbb R}$ satisfing $W \cap AW=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Let $V=W \oplus AW$. Then
$V$ is invariant by $A$ also. Suppose that $V \neq K_{\mathbb R}$ ; then, we have a vector $x$ in $K_{\mathbb R}$ but not in $V$. Let $V'={\sf span}(x)\oplus V$. I claim that $Ax\not\in V'$. For otherwise, we would have some $\gamma\in{\mathbb R}$ 
such that $t_1=Ax-\gamma x \in V$. Then $t_2=A(Ax-\gamma x) \in V$, but
$t_2=A(Ax-\gamma x)=(2\alpha)Ax-x-\gamma Ax$. Then $t_3=t_2+(\gamma-2\alpha)t_1 \in V$, but $t_3=-((\gamma-\alpha)^2+\beta^2)x$. That would imply $x\in V$, a contradiction.
All this shows that $W'=W\oplus {\sf span}(x)$ still satisfies $W' \cap AW'=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. So if we take a $W$ of maximal dimension with this property, we must have
$K_{\mathbb R}=W \oplus AW$. Let $(x^1,x^2,\ldots ,x^t)$ be a basis (in ${\mathbb R}^n$)
of $W$. Put $y^i=\frac{\alpha x-Ax}{\beta}$. Then $(y^1,y^2,\ldots ,y^t)$ forms
a basis for $AW$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$, and 
$(x^1\pm i y^1,x^2\pm i y^2, \ldots, x^t\pm i y^t)$ forms a basis of
$K_{\mathbb C}$. So, in (1) we may assume without loss that the family 
$(x_j,y_j)_{1\leq j \leq s}$ is linearly independent.

The $b_k,x_j,y_j$ form a basis of ${\mathbb R}^n$ when taken together. Then, the scalar product for which this basis is orthonormal is preserved by $A$.

Comment: Actually I don't really understand how you find the $f_j$ and $g_j$. Precisely, why do their coefficients belong to $\mathbb{R}$ since the diagonalization ii over $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: @SelimGhazouani Please see my updated version.

Comment: Ok I understand how you want to proceed but now we should check that $e_i,x_j,y_j$ actually form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. I think that using computation you used to prove that $x_j$ and $y_j$ are linearly independent should work but I doesn't seem obvious.

Comment: @SelimGhazouani This follows from the fact that the $e_j$ and the $x_j+iy_j$ form a basis (of eigenvectors) over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I'm not sure. Here you are using the fact that complex eigenvalues are conjugates, and for each pair of conjugate you use only one eigenvector and take the real and imaginary part. DO you see what I mean ?

Comment: @SelimGhazouani Please see my updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$ and all its eigenvalues have unit moduli. Then $A=PDP^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $P$ and some unitary diagonal matrix $D$. Let $P=USV^\ast$ be a singular value decomposition and let $G = US^{-2}U^\ast$. Then $G$ is positive definite and
$$
A^\ast GA = (US^{-1}V^\ast D^\ast VSU^\ast)(US^{-2}U^\ast)(USV^\ast D VS^{-1}U^\ast) = G.
$$
Hence $A$ preserves the inner product induced by $G$.